# How to include data from fetch.php to Angular JS

Tags: php, angularjs

http://jsfiddle.net/rzgWr/19/ - demo

I`m greate getdata.php

```
include 'db.php';
$sel = mysqli_query($link,"select * from products");
$data = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sel)) {
 $data[] = array("name"=>$row['name'],"shirt"=>$row['shirt'],"pants"=>$row['pants'],"shoes"=>$row['shoes']);
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Demo having next code with value $scope.players:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, filterFilter) {
    $scope.usePants = {};
    $scope.useShirts = {};
    $scope.useShoes = {};

    $scope.players = [
        {name: 'Bruce Wayne', shirt: 'XXL', pants: '42', shoes: '12'},
        {name: 'Wayne Gretzky', shirt: 'XL', pants: '38', shoes: '10'},
        {name: 'Michael Jordan', shirt: 'M', pants: '32', shoes: '9'},
        {name: 'Rodman', shirt: 'XSXL', pants: '42', shoes: '11'},
        {name: 'Jake Smitz', shirt: 'XXL', pants: '42', shoes: '12'},
        {name: 'Will Will', shirt: 'XXLL', pants: '42', shoes: '12'},
        {name: 'Youasdf Oukls', shirt: 'XL', pants: '38', shoes: '10'},
        {name: 'Sam Sneed', shirt: 'XL', pants: '38', shoes: '10'},
        {name: 'Bill Waxy', shirt: 'M', pants: '32', shoes: '9'},
        {name: 'Javier Xavior', shirt: 'M', pants: '32', shoes: '9'},
        {name: 'Bill Knight', shirt: 'M', pants: '32', shoes: '9'},        
        {name: 'One More', shirt: 'M', pants: '32', shoes: '9'},        
        {name: 'Player One', shirt: 'XXL', pants: '42', shoes: '11'},
        {name: 'Space Cadet', shirt: 'XXL', pants: '42', shoes: '12'},
        {name: 'Player Two', shirt: 'XXXXL', pants: '42', shoes: '12'}
    ];
```

How to load $scope.players from getdata.php ?

Thanks.

---

How do it correctly?

```
myApp.controller('playersCrtl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
    $http.get('getdata.php').success(function(data){
         $scope.players = data;
    });
```

Comment: by making request to server i.e.  ajax

Comment: How do it correctly? myApp.controller('playersCrtl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
    $http.get('getdata.php').success(function(data){
        $scope.players = data;
    });

Comment: not work if I put this instead  $scope.players = [];